# How to apply method datatable to table which is created on a fly

Tags: javascript, datatable, html-table

I'm creating table dynamically via button click event

```
function createTable() {
    $.ajax ({
        url: 'php/GetData.php', 
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {id:25},
        success: function(msg){
            var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
            var tableString = "<table id='tbla' class='display'><thead><tr><th>Name<th>Age<th>Birthday</tr></thead><tbody>";

            for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
                //alert(obj[i].name);
                tableString += gg_stringformat("<tr><td>{0}<td>{1}<td>{2}</tr>", obj[i].name, obj[i].age, obj[i].birthday);
            }

            tableString += "</tbody></table>";
            //alert(tableString);

            $('#divb').html(tableString);
            $('#tbla').dataTable();
        }
    });
}
```

Method

> $('#tbla').dataTable();

doesn't work. 
 When I place this line in `$(document).ready(function(){.....});` error occurs and and nothing is visible. Because the table with this id, still not presented. How does achieve this task?

All appropriate files are linked properly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/dataTables.min.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/dataTables.min.js"></script>





function gg_stringformat() {
var argcount = arguments.length,
    string,
    i;

if (!argcount) {
    return "";
}
if (argcount === 1) {
    return arguments[0];
}
string = arguments[0];
for (i = 1; i < argcount; i++) {
    string = string.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + (i - 1) + '}', 'gi'), arguments[i]);
}
return string;
}
```

Comment: Does it not work initializing it in the ajax success as shown in the question code?

Comment: Please include the exact text of the error.

Comment: @Tom Error not appears, but JavaScript not works due to error.

Comment: @GGSoft: In that case, I think it's incorrect to say an error occurs. The browser is quite possibly doing what it thinks you want, and doing so successfully. This is an important difference. Perhaps there's CSS that is hiding the table. Perhaps `#divb` doesn't exist when the function executes. Perhaps `msg` has `length` 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in the HTML you're using to construct the table. You don't close any of the `<th>` or `<td>` tags. That could very well be causing the problem.

Rather than `alert`, try doing `console.log(tableString)` at the end, and then examine the output to see if it is valid HTML.

Also, try commenting out the final call to `dataTable`, and see whether the function is at least capable of constructing the basic table.

If none of those things resolve it, perhaps the problem is with the XHR call. Is `msg` shaped the way you expect? Is there a bug in `gg_stringformat`?

Comment: Table appaears in div. That means, all is ok with creation of table. gg_stringformat only provides string formatting.`function gg_stringformat() {
    var argcount = arguments.length,
        string,
        i;

    if (!argcount) {
        return "";
    }
    if (argcount === 1) {
        return arguments[0];
    }
    string = arguments[0];
    for (i = 1; i < argcount; i++) {
        string = string.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + (i - 1) + '}', 'gi'), arguments[i]);
    }
    return string;
}`

Comment: In that case, you should check the documentation for "DataTables." I don't recognize the name, and your post doesn't provide enough information for me to figure out what to research, but the filenaming suggests it's part of some framework. Ensure that the table you're building satisfies its requirements. Perhaps you're invoking it incorrectly.

Comment: this function now is included in question.

Comment: [link](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)

Comment: I don't think we need to see the `gg_stringformat`. It seems obvious we've ruled that out as a possible source of error. The problem is likely a mismatch between what DataTable expects and what you're providing.

Comment: gg_stringformat works fine, I guaranteed.  Code is in question.

Comment: Now I will apply code on static table. Maybe it's due to datatable.js

Comment: I'm sure it's not impossible. Datatable's docs say that "the table must be valid, well formatted HTML, with a header (thead) and a single body (tbody)." The malformed HTML in `tableString` may be the culprit. Another possibility that I think is quite likely is that the code is working perfectly, but datatable's CSS is producing undesirable results. It may make layout assumptions that are not valid in your environment, with the result that the table shrinks down to width or height 0px. Try removing just the CSS file and see if the table appears.

Comment: I had some corrupted  local files downloaded. When I use CDN all works fine

Comment: Good find. I would not have predicted that. I think you should post that as an answer and accept that instead of mine. Include any information about how you originally downloaded the files, what form the corruption took, and how you discovered the problem.

Comment: When I download file I have looked into with notepad++. (Was interesting), maybe then I have typed something.